# Javascript variable scope undefined

Tags: javascript

I want to define a variable to default value if not already defined but found a strange issue.

`var x =  x || {}` works whereas `x  = x || {}` gives an error.

Output from firebug.

```
>>> a = a || {};
ReferenceError: a is not defined
[Break On This Error]   
a = a || {};
with(_... {}; }; (line 2)
>>> var b = b || {};
undefined

>>> b;
Object {}
>>> a;
ReferenceError: a is not defined
[Break On This Error]
```

why does the first one give error while the second seems to go through.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/difference-between-using-var-and-not-using-var-in-javascript?

Comment: this answer will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/1470494/205585

Comment: There are real duplicates on this, those aren't one of them.

Comment: Due to [variable hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting), the definition of `b` is hoisted to the top of the scope so that `b` is defined as a local variable before the assignment operation takes place.  The same does not happen for `a`, because it is not defined with `var`.

Comment: Demonstration of hoisting (@apsillers): http://jsfiddle.net/meM9P/ Notice `z` is never defined, but `zz` while later defined, returns the `uh oh zz` on that check.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `var`.  Except for a bug on old IE versions, adding the `var` saves you an error message and makes it clear that you're not assuming it is declared elsewhere.

On those old versions of IE,

```
x = (typeof x !== 'undefined' && x) || {}
```

a `typeof` check prevents the "undeclared variable" error.

Comment: If you are going for old IE, then it's not going to work for this bug http://jsfiddle.net/NBg7j/ (Gives error in IE8 compatibility mode)

Comment: @Esailija, good point.  I was assuming there was a `var` somewhere and the IE bug I was talking about causes re-initialization to `undefined` when there are `var`s in two `<script>` elements.  If you have an id/name overlap, you have to have a `var` somewhere.

Comment: Won't the first return `true` to `x`?

Comment: @JaredFarrish, no.  `(a && b)` returns `b` when `a` is truthy or `a` otherwise.  `(a || b)` returns `b` when `a` is falsey or `a` otherwise.

Comment: @Jared, In case you're interested, the semantics are defined at http://es5.github.com/#x11.11

Comment: In retrospect, I think I knew that in the back of my mind (sorta), just interesting to see it in action more or less. I'd seen the `x || y` syntax before, I just didn't translate that over to the other operators and how they would work. Thanks for the link.